# JSP compilation errors on oc4j 10.1.3.4.0

Tags: jsp, oc4j

I have two web apps, App A and App B. On my local standalone OC4J, both work fine. When I deploy them to a remote OC4J (not the standalone version), App A works fine but for App B I get JSP compilation errors for every single JSP I try and display. A regular HTML file will display fine, though. Both web apps are wrapped in a separate EAR file, and it's the same EAR files that are being deployed onto both systems. Below is a sample of the output from the application.log file.
There doesn't seem to be any hint whatsoever in any log file as to why the JSPs can't compile. The web.xml, application.xml and orion-application.xml look fine. Could I possibly be missing some jar file in my deployment? What in the world is the source of this problem?

```
14/07/09 16:05:01.39 ifactory-security: JspServlet: unable to dispatch to requested page: oracle.jsp.provider.JspCompileException: <H3>Errors compiling:/icu/ias/dev/ifactory/10.1.3/j2ee/ifactory/application-deployments/ifactory-security/ifactory-security/persistence/_pages//_simple.java</H3><pre></pre>
    at oracle.jsp.app.JspJavacCompiler.compile(JspJavacCompiler.java:304)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageCompiler.attemptCompilePage(JspPageCompiler.java:731)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageCompiler.compileBothModes(JspPageCompiler.java:456)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageCompiler.compilePage(JspPageCompiler.java:413)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageInfo.compileAndLoad(JspPageInfo.java:705)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.compileAndServe(JspPageTable.java:694)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.service(JspPageTable.java:414)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java:594)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:518)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.icumed.ifactory3.web.common.ServletRequestListener.doFilter(ServletRequestListener.java:79)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:623)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:370)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:889)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:453)
    at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:313)
    at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:199)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.procClientSocket(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:234)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.access$700(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:29)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler$AcceptHandlerHorse.run(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:879)
    at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. In the problem environment, we had recently upgraded the version of Java. However, a mistake was made and OC4J ended up using the JRE instead of the JDK, so there was no compiler present.